# How to catch the data of each cell during FullRowEditing - ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

On ag-grid, during a Full Row Editing I need to know if all cells has value during the edition to enable or not the button which let user to summit the updated row data. In order to get that, I´m trying to catch the data is entering on each cell during the cell edition. I can get the previous data with cellEditingStarted and later data with cellEditingStopped, but how could get the data during the edition?

[image: FullRowEditing]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever actually used full-row editing, but I have written quite a few cell editors, and from what I see in the documentation, full-row editing is just like single-cell editing, except that all of the row's cell editors are enabled at the same time.

The only other apparent difference is that there is an additional 'rowValueChanged' event emitted when all of the cell editors stop editing (at the same time).

So, by default, while the row is in edit mode, you don't get any events.

I think that to do what you want, you would have to implement custom cell editors for all of your editable columns, and find some way for them to communicate with the parent component while still in edit mode.

I'm thinking that maybe you could supply a callback function to the cell editors via the cell editor parameters, and use that to have each editor communicate its status to the parent component.